# Find closed form for infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have such equation:
$$
R_{odd}=\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}
\frac{2}{x_{2}-x_{1}}\left[\frac{D(2i+1)^{2}\pi^{2}}{(x_{2}-x_{1})^{2}}+\frac{1}{\tau}\right]^{-1}
$$
I know that closed form exists, but I cannot find it, I tried sympy, but haven't succeed.
Do you know a way to do it in any symbolic algebra software?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/)?

Comment: no, but is there any free open source package?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha allows some calculations for free...

Comment: It says that computation time exceeded

Comment: well, then I can't help

Comment: With proper algebra you end up needing to find a closed form fro $b\sum_{i}\left[D(2i+1)^2 + a\right]^{-1}$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ but obviously, given that you haven't really said anything about $D$, we can't do anything else.

Comment: All except k are constants

Answer (score 4):

If we suppose that all parameters are positive constants, we can get a closed form of the sum.
$$S_0=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{2}{x_{2}-x_{1}}\left[\frac{D(2k+1)^{2}\pi^{2}}{(x_{2}-x_{1})^{2}}+\frac{1}{\tau}\right]^{-1}=\frac{x_2-x_1}{2\pi^2D}\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+\frac12)^2+\frac{(x_2-x_2)^2}{4\pi^2D\tau}}$$
$$=\frac{x_2-x_1}{4\pi^2D}\left(\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+\frac12)^2+\frac{(x_2-x_2)^2}{4\pi^2D\tau}}-\frac{2}{\frac14+\frac{(x_2-x_2)^2}{4\pi^2D\tau}}-\frac{2}{\frac94+\frac{(x_2-x_2)^2}{4\pi^2D\tau}}\right)\tag{1}$$
Denoting $\displaystyle a^2=\frac{(x_2-x_2)^2}{4\pi^2D\tau}$, we have to evaluate $\displaystyle S_0=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+\frac12)^2+a^2}$

The approach is standart: we evaluate the integral in the complex plane along a big circle with the radius $R\to\infty$:
$$\oint\frac{\pi\cot\pi z}{(z+\frac12)^2+a^2}dz=0=2\pi i\left(S_0+\underset{z=-\frac12\pm ia}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{\pi\cot\pi z}{(z+\frac12)^2+a^2}\right)$$
$$\Rightarrow\,S_0=-\frac{\pi\cot\pi(-\frac12+ia)}{2ia}+\frac{\pi\cot\pi(-\frac12-ia)}{2ia}=\frac{\pi\tanh\pi a}{a}\tag{2}$$
Putting (2) into (1)
$$S=\frac{x_2-x_1}{4\pi^2D}\left(\frac{\pi\tanh\pi a}{a}-\frac{8}{1+4a^2}-\frac{8}{9+4a^2}\right)\,\bigg|_{a=\frac{x_2-x_1}{2\pi\sqrt{D\tau}}}$$

Comment: @Георгий WolframAlpha can verify the result for the reparameterized sum [$S_0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+1%2F%28%28k%2B1%2F2%29%5E2%2Ba%5E2%29+from+k%3D-infinity+to+%2Binfinity) (but tends to break down and cry when it sees too many variables)

Comment: Oh, thank you a lot, but I am not sure I can repeat it if I need evaluate another function...But still thanks a lot!

Comment: Your sum index is $k$ or $i$?

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash I used $k$ instead - just not to mix with $i=\sqrt{-1}$, as soon as complex integration is involved. Correcting the typo ) Thank you.